# Angular Form to C# MVC Entity Controller null values

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

TRying to send data from angularjs to C# mvc controller. Although data are collected well(I see them with console.log), they do not receive well in the C# controller and so, null values are stored in the database..
Here is my Angular code:

```
 var formapp = angular.module("formapp", []);
       formapp.controller("formctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                      $scope.submitFormAngular = function () {
                var animal = $scope.animal;
                var url = '/Home/AngularData';
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: animal,
                }).success(function (data) {
                    console.log($scope.animal);
                    console.log("worked");
                           })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                console.log("not worked");
                            });
            }
           });
```

here is my C# DTO:

```
public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int animalID { get; set; }
    public string animalName { get; set; }
    public string animalHabitat { get; set; }
    public string animalClass { get; set; }

}
```

and finally this is my C# controller:

```
public JsonResult AngularData(Animal animal)
{
    db.Animals.Add(animal);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
}
```

Again: even values are stored in the UI, they do not pass to the C# code.
I a new in Angular etc.
Any help is welcome.

This is my html code for the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Name</strong></label>
        <input name="name"
               id="name"
               type="text"
               maxlength="80"
               ng-model="animal.name"
               required
               placeholder="write a name" />
             <!--  data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">-->
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="habitat" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Habitat</strong></label>
        <input name="habitat"
               id="habitat"
               type="text"
               ng-model="animal.habitat"
               required
               placeholder="write a habitat" />
              <!-- data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">-->
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="class" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Class</strong></label>
        <input name="class"
               id="class"
               type="text"
               ng-model="animal.class"
               required
                placeholder="write a class" />
              <!-- data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">-->
    </div>
```

Comment: what data it is passing to the controller, check the data in Network tab in developer tools

Comment: is it webApiController or MVC controller ?

Comment: @GANI it is a C# MVC controller. I see the data in the Network tab pretty well. I cannot find out why they do not been received from the C# controller

Comment: add [HttpPost] on the action method

Comment: Is your controller function being hit?

Comment: @GANI I do have [HttpPost] above the controller.

Comment: @Rani Radcliff  Controller hits(I placed breakpoint). Although, it stores null values to the database. ppfff can't find the problem

Comment: Curious why you are using an angular controller, but jQuery ajax? Why not use Angular's $http or $resource services?

Comment: @Scottie I am firstly trying just to see the result I want, not familiar with all this.

Comment: @GeorgeD Ahh... my bad.  I missed that you ARE using angular $http.

Comment: Do you have Fiddler installed?  If not, you should install that and watch the actual request to see what data is actually being passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124441/discussion-between-scottie-and-georged).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked with GeorgeD and figured out that he had his angular form models defined as

```
ng-model='animal.name'
```

instead of

```
ng-model='animal.animalName'
```

Changing this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller function to:

```
public Task<ActionResult> AngularData(Animal animal)
{
    db.Animals.Add(animal);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
}
```

Then check to see if anything is in "animal" before it does the commit to the database.

Comment: I get an error on "Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });" **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'**

Comment: Task wouldn't matter here.  You need an await if you're going to use Task.

Comment: @Scottie I'm pretty sure that you only need await if it is public async Task.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Oh, yep, you're correct! However, Task wouldn't make any difference in accepting the model.  Only on what gets returned.

Comment: @GeorgeD wa there anything in "animal"?  Did you put a breakpoint at db.Animlas.Add(animal) to see what if anything is in animal?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I get null values there

Comment: Okay, please post your HTML form so we can see how the model is being applied.  "animal" needs to have animal.animalID, animal.animalName, etc.  The models have to match exactly.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff please have a look on my updated question. I placed the html code. I do not define the animalID because i set the keyword [Key] on my DTO. So (I believe) that aimaIlD is been generated by itself. When values are stored in database, aimallD has a value but aimalName, aimalHabitat and aimalClass have not

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you are using animal like form data.  Do you have $scope.animal = {}; at the top of your controller?